# Cache a completable?

Tags: android, google-maps, rx-java

I'm trying RxJava and I've found a small problem that I don't know how to handle.
I'm using in my application google maps API, so when the fragment with maps is created I have to call

```
mGoogleMapFragment.getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback)
```

this will call a callback method when map is ready to be used. Looks like a great place to use RxJava to signal that the map is ready and I can do some work on it. So I've started with something like this:

```
    mMapReadySignal = Single.<GoogleMap>fromEmitter(objectEmitter -> {
        OnMapReadyCallback callback = googleMap -> {
            mMap = googleMap;
            objectEmitter.onSuccess(googleMap);
        };
        getMapAsync(callback);
    }).cache();
```

Cache is called to forbid multiple subscriptions to happen - I just want to subscribe once.

Then I'm using this Single in two other observables:

```
    mMapReadySignal
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe((googleMap) -> {
                LatLng place = new LatLng(52,0, 20.0);
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(13.0f));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(place));
            }));
```

and

```
    MyRetrofitInterface.getMarkedPlaces()
            .zipWith(mMapReadySignal.toObservable(), (markedPlaces, ignore) -> markedPlaces)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(
                    markedPlaces -> showOnMap(markedPlaces),
                    Throwable::printStackTrace));
```

Looks nice, but can look even better - I don't use anywhere object returned by mMapReadySignal. So why don't make it a Completable?

```
    mMapReadySignal = Completable.fromEmitter(objectEmitter -> {
        OnMapReadyCallback callback = googleMap -> {
            mMap = googleMap;
            objectEmitter.onCompleted();
        };
        getMapAsync(callback);
    });
```

And here's the problem. I cannot call cache on a completable object, so what I've ended up with is that mMapReadySignal is subscribed twice. That's definately not what I want! How can I turn this Completable to be cached? Is there a way?

Oh and yes - I've been thinking about moving that "moveCamera observable" to the body of completable's emitter. However this is not a solution to my problem, as this would create an oportunity for a bug - if I'd remove all subscribers to mMapReadySignal, noone will subscribe to it, therefore I'd end up with a googleMap without camera moved to my desired position;

Answer (score 2):

as Completable doesn't emit nothing (no onNext) there is no sense of Cache to it (no events to cache).
However, you can achieve this by transferring the Completeable to Observable using Completable.toObservable() method, than cache this Observable using Observable.cache(), than transfer it again to Completable.
you can also just create Observable with the operation, cache it, and then call transfer it to completable using toCompletable()

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to cache a completable.

```
final Completable c = Completable.fromAction(new Action0() {
    @Override
    public void call() {

    }
});

c.observeOn(Schedulers.computation()).subscribe(new Action0() {
    @Override
    public void call() {
        Log.d("X", "A");
    }
});

try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {}

c.observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(new Action0() {
    @Override
    public void call() {
        Log.d("X", "B");
    }
});
```

prints out 'A', then two seconds later, 'B'.